# Не работает position relative

Tags: html, css

Есть такая разметка

```css
.blockSearchFastResult {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border: #1393d9 solid 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
  background: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 9pt;
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: none;
  width: 484px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shop-search">
  <div>
    <form action="#" method="post" class="shop-search-form blockSearch">
      <label class="search-form-label">
        <input type="text" class="search-form-input" placeholder="Поиск по товарам">
        <button type="submit" class="search-form-icon" title="Поиск"></button>
      </label>
    </form>
    <div class="blockSearchFastResult">
      123
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Хотелось бы реализовать выпадающее окна после введения букв. Техническая часть работает нормально, но вот блок `blockSearchFastResult` выпадает в самом углу, и настроить не получается, т.к. при каждом расширении будет выглядить по разному. 
Как сделать так что бы этот блок открывался прям под формой с `z-index: 100`. Пример на этом [сайте](http://esatekstil.kz/). В поиск вбейте "полотенце" и увидите слева выпадающий блок

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/Kvbf/ypzcNw5nU   не сбоку

Comment: элементу, который будет выпадать, ставишь position: `absolute`, а его родителю `position: relative`. тогда он будет позиционироваться всегда относительно родителя. и там уже свойствами `left` и `top` позиционируй

Answer (score 2):

```
.shop-search{
position: relative;
}
```

Теперь может позиционировать выпадающее окно относительно .shop-search

Answer (score 2):

Задать блоку `Parent` свойство `position:relative`, тогда все внутренние элементы будут позиционироваться относительно его.

```
<div class="shop-search">
  <div class="Parent">
    <form action="#" method="post" class="shop-search-form blockSearch">
        <label class="search-form-label">
            <input type="text" class="search-form-input" placeholder="Поиск по товарам">
            <button type="submit" class="search-form-icon" title="Поиск"></button>
        </label>
    </form>
    <div class="blockSearchFastResult">
      123
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Вот как-то так :)

```
 .Parent { 
    position:relative;
 }
```